# lamp Ubuntu Debian php7 как понизить версию

Tags: linux, apache, веб-программирование, frontend, lamp

Добрый день, проблема в следующем, ос Ubuntu 16 , на ней установлен lamp последней версии, в нем же стоит php7. Для работы моего приложения требуется php максимум 5,4, его уже нет в оф репозитории, есть токо в ppa, но от туда брать стремно, как можно альтернативно решить вопрос, ведь насколько я понимаю, если приложение для php5-x то в php7-x половина всего работать не будет ? , мож хто какой-то другой стик на линуксе использует ?

Comment: А зачем lamp вообще нужен? Apache установлен уже будет. Двумя командами так сложно установить мускул с php? И что значит, что php5 нет в официальном репозитории? А репозиторий от 14-й убунты неофициальный? Команду apt-get install php5 отменили?

Comment: да я и пытаюсь его поставить apt-get install , но ставится php7 , phpmyadmin то же самое,

Comment: тоесть вы предлагаете руцями прописать репы от 14 убунты ?

Comment: Т.е. Вы ставите 5-й php, а ставится 7-й? P.S.: Прочитайте справку (справа) к этому ресурсу, чтобы знать как правильно писать комментарии.

Comment: *максимум 5,4* — [в ubuntu 14.04 уже версия выше (5.5), есть ниже (5.3) — в ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: tdc@chromebook:~$ sudo apt-get install php
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php-common php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json
  php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
Предлагаемые пакеты:
  php-pear
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
  php php-common php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json
  php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
обновлено 0, установлено 9 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 16 пакетов не обновлено.

Comment: tdc@chromebook:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-cli
Пакет php5-cli недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.
Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list
Однако следующие пакеты могут его заменить:
  php7.0-cli:i386 php7.0-cli
E: Для пакета «php5-cli» не найден кандидат на установку

Comment: А если завтра понадобиться php 5.5? то что, снова перелопачивать систему и заставить ужиться между собой? и правильный ответ звучит так - `apt install docker; docker run -it nextcloudci/php5.4:1.0.10 /bin/bash` и будет Вам терминал с нужным php..

Comment: Вадим большое спасибо , я читал ваш. Развернутый коммент по поводу docker, даже голосовал за ответ, но я до конца не понял че это и счем его едят , принцип понятен что все по, зависимости, когфликты не могут возникнуть потому как все в контейнере , спросил  у хостеров, они в шоке от вопрса ,говорят ну давайте перелазить на vps и будем пробовать ,а я вообше не понимаю как его там развернуть ,если можете обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: docker нужно просто установить, как обычную программу. И можете считать, что это просто легковесная виртуальная машина. А вот с хостерами - тут другая история. Может проще найти себе хостера, который будет поддерживать докер "из коробки"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотя вам и сказали, что можно подключить реп от 14.04LTS, можно просто

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

и вам менеджер явно пишет:

> Пакет php5-cli недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
>   пакета.

Но вы упорно пишете

```
tdc@chromebook:~$ sudo apt-get install php
```

Но если вы не можете добавить 5 к "инсталлу"
Тогда вам путь к "многоверсионности" PHP
Для этого есть хорошие маны для утилит PhpBrew и suphp:
phpbrew - https://habrahabr.ru/post/210764/
suphp - https://habrahabr.ru/post/245549/  (yum смените на apt-get)